# Java program at 100% CPU utilization, program locked

Tags: java

After executing for a long time, I have a Java program that goes to 100% CPU utilization.  However, it's not clear looking at jmc which thread is causing the 100% utilization.  What else can I look at here to see what is causing the issue?

[image: Finalizer Blocked]

Comment: Its propably because you had left open a RMI connection, but your question is really unclear

Comment: This is what the finalizer doesn't when it doesn't have anything to do and is completely normal.

Comment: When your application "locks up", which thread do you expect to be doing something? I suggest you look at that one.

Comment: @Ferrybig: I've added some information to my question.  What other information can I add to my question to make it more clear?

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I should have specified.  CPU utilization for my program is at 100%.  However, it looks like no thread is doing anything except for the Finalizer.  None of my objects have finalize() methods.

Comment: @Dave You can for example add the stack trace of all threads to the question (mainly the threads that are running), or list what technologies you use, for example the 100% cpu utilization that you just mentioned may even be the key in the problem.

Comment: @Dave which thread should be doing something when you attempt what you are going?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Java Profiler trial version.